# Windows Logon box shows empty computer name

Tags: windows-xp

I think i definitely overflowed on this one ... my windows logon dialog shows empty for (this computer) option. I just reloaded XP a couple of weeks ago and its at SP3 level. I travel all the time, I just got back to the office,  connected to the LAN (no change to domain or computername), rebooted and viola' the dialog with no computername shows up ...

It doesnt allow me to logon as a domain user or domain admin as well. I cannot login in safe mode. essentially, I am SOL

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: have you tried rebooting?

Answer (score 1):

You could try a repair installation. That normally fixes weird, seemingly unfixable problems with windows.